# ZK selectbox static list not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, zk

I am trying to implement ZK selectbox. It works fine whenever i try to use it with model like this

```
<zscript>
    <![CDATA[
      String[] numbers = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
      ListModelList _newModel= new ListModelList(numbers);
    ]]>
</zscript> 

<selectbox id="testSelectBox">
    <template name="model" model="${_newModel}">
       <label value="${each}" />
    </template>
</selectbox>
```

But my question can i use it like this?

```
<selectbox id="testSelectBox"  sclass="pagingCombo">
    <template name="model">
      <label value="10" />
      <label value="25" />
      <label value="50" />
      <label value="100" />
    </template>
</selectbox>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you use static data, you don't need to set a template.
example for listbox :

```
<listbox>
      <listitem height="30px">
              <listcell label="ZK Jet 0.8.0 is released" />
              <listcell label="2008/11/17 17:41:29" />
      </listitem>
      <listitem height="30px">
              <listcell label="URLs for iPhone-Optimized Google Sites" />
              <listcell label="2008/11/17 15:56:37" />
      </listitem
</listbox>
```

**But**, [selectbox doesn't allow any children](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Selectbox#Supported_Children), **therefor you will always need to use a model.**
Of course, we can look at the renderer for selectbox :

```
new org.zkoss.zul.ItemRenderer() {
        public String render(Component owner, Object data, int index) throws Exception {
            return data.toString();
        }
    };
```

And there again, we see that we return a `String` and don't have a `Listcell` or `Row` where we could add `Label` or whatever we want.
The component we receive in the renderer is the parent component.

Comment: Actually i want to use selectbox not Listbox.

Comment: I don't say you need to use listbox, I'm saying you need to use a ListModel in order to let this work.

Comment: That's what i figured anyway thanks for your help , I ended up using Listbox.

Comment: No problem, but listbox doesn't have same functionality as selectbox.  I do agree, this functionality should be possible on selectbox also.

Comment: i used it with mold="select" so basically ui will be same.